# How to switch ON/OFF ion-toggle by swipe only?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic4

[[image]
<sup>click to view full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGEqw.png)

I want a condition that ion-toggle only switched by swipe instead of click/tap/press. here is my code:

```
<ion-toggle 
    *ngIf="status === 'akan menjemput' || status === 'menunggu diproses'" 
    class="jemput customswipe" 
    (ionChange)="swipe($event,'sedang menjemput')"
   >
</ion-toggle>
```

If i use ***disable*** on toggle, it won't let me to interact for sure. So this is not what i looking for. I hope you can help me, thanks!